# Why must override function: writeToParcel from interface Parcelable in android?

Tags: android, parcelable

I have a class: `class PartStoreModel implements Parcelable` which contains some properties such as: `id, name, address`. In this function I must `override` function: `public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags)` (I left this function empty, don't do anything):

```
@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
// Do nothing here
}

// This is how I save on configuration change:
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putParcelableArrayList(KEY_INVENTORY_GROUP_SAVED,
            mPartStoreModels);
}
```

The problem is that **It worked perfect!**. So why I have to override `writeToParcel` function, when I can leave it blank? Can anyone explains it? (I usually override `writeToParcel` function, and `PartStoreModel(Parcel in)` as `write` and `read` function, but nothing is better than leave them blank!)